# AttributeError: module 'scipy.sparse' has no attribute 'coo_array'

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter, conda, attributeerror

Getting this error in my Jupyter Notebook
What would be the best way to fix this utilizing conda instead of pip

I've attempted `conda upgrade --all` and that didnt seem to work

Comment: `coo_matrix` should work.  `coo_array` is a new thing.  As far as I can tell the `array` versions are largely a semantic addition.  They don't add any new functionality.

Comment: Trying to use a function that requires coo_array

Comment: What function?   What module?

Comment: networkx library in python.  I am unable to do a few things without that library for some reason

Comment: Can you use a slightly older `networkx`?

Comment: I think it might be an issue with scipy. I've tried downgrading it but I keep getting this error. he following packages are not available from current channels:

  - scipy=1.8.0

`conda install scipy=1.8.0`

Comment: I have a fairly recent `conda` installation.  `scipy` version is '1.7.3'. `networkx` is '2.7.1'.  `nx.to_scipy_sparse_array` uses `coo_array`, There is a `to_scipy_sparse_matrix`, but that also uses `to_scipy_sparse_array` with a migration note.  Looks like they jumped the gun on migrating to `coo_array` - updating the `networkx` before the `scipy` version was updated.

Comment: Someone complained about this last March, and they were told - just upgrade your scipy; close.  Not very helpful.  I don't know conda well enough to downgrade my `networkx` to a working version.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `scipy.sparse.*_array` functions were introduced with v1.8. The `networkx` package started requiring `scipy >=1.8` with v2.7. So, either upgrade SciPy

```
conda install 'scipy>=1.8'
```

or downgrade NetworkX:

```
conda install 'networkx<2.7'
```

Part of the issue here is that, at [the recommendation of a `networkx` developer](https://github.com/conda-forge/networkx-feedstock/issues/1#issuecomment-1047181328), Conda Forge stopped explicitly requiring `scipy` as a dependency of `networkx`, and therefore there is no longer any constraint. I opened [an issue on the feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/networkx-feedstock/issues/42) to revisit coinstallation constraints (`run_constrained` specifications).

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in [this Github comment](https://github.com/pyg-team/pytorch_geometric/issues/4378#issuecomment-1369373606), I was trying to calculate the page rank (`networkx.pagerank`) of a graph on Google Colab when I encountered the same error. After executing the following code, the issue was resolved for me:

```
!pip install --upgrade scipy networkx
```

> **A Side Note**: `pip install` refers to installing packages and leave the package as-is if it is already installed. But the `--upgrade` flag instructs `pip` to uninstall anything which is being upgraded/replaced. For more info on this, refer [this official doc](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#overview).

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similar error
I could solve it by installing these versions of newtorkx and scipy:

`!pip install 'networkx<2.7'`

`!pip install 'scipy>=1.8'`

Answer (score 0):

```bash
!pip install 'networkx<2.7'
```

seems to work, even with the latest version of `scipy` installed.